# Saving a transliteration table in perl

Tags: perl, transliteration

I want to transliterate digits from 1 - 8 with 0 but not knowing the number at compile time. Since transliterations do not interpolate variables I'm doing this:

```
@trs = (sub{die},sub{${$_[0]} =~ tr/[0,1]/[1,0]/},sub{${$_[0]} =~ tr/[0,2]/[2,0]/},sub{${$_[0]} =~ tr/[0,3]/[3,0]/},sub{${$_[0]} =~ tr/[0,4]/[4,0]/},sub{${$_[0]} =~ tr/[0,5]/[5,0]/},sub{${$_[0]} =~ tr/[0,6]/[6,0]/},sub{${$_[0]} =~ tr/[0,7]/[7,0]/},sub{${$_[0]} =~ tr/[0,8]/[8,0]/});
```

and then index it like:

```
$trs[$character_to_transliterate](\$var_to_change);
```

I would appreciate if anyone can point me to a best looking solution.

Comment: `tr/[0,1]/[1,0]/`  could be (should be) written as `tr/01/10/`

Comment: The `[,]` characters don't add anything to the expression (and may actually make it less efficient). It is equivalent to, say, `tr/],[01/],[10/`. They might mislead a newbie Perl programmer who encounters your code that they have something to do with the syntax of `tr`.

Comment: The tr/// operator doesn't understand regular expression patterns or character classes ([a-z], [a-z0-9], etc.), it uses simple lists and ranges of characters.

I recommend that you review perldoc perlop on the command line or visit http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr%2fSEARCHLIST%2fREPLACEMENTLIST%2fcds for a refresher.

Comment: [0,1] works right, it is not less efficient and it looks better so I'll stick with it.

Comment: @user: `[0,1]` it may work right, but it's extremely misleading. Read mob's second comment, and converter's.

Comment: @user246100 but it only works by *accident* and you have no clue *why* it works, and so when it breaks, you will have no clue why it broke.

Comment: when it gets broken I will send you a letter apologizing for not having listen to you

Comment: @user246100: Wow, I can't imagine how much fun you must have tracking down segfaults because you handled your memory in a way that looks better and works correctly completely by accident... but then, maybe you don't use any languages where that can happen.

Answer (score 2):

Any time that you are repeating yourself, you should see if what you are doing can be done in a loop.  Since `tr` creates its tables at compile time, you can use `eval` to access the compiler at runtime:

```
my @trs = (sub {die}, map {eval "sub {\$_[0] =~ tr/${_}0/0$_/}"} 1 .. 8);

my $x = 123;

$trs[2]($x);

print "$x\n"; # 103
```

There is also no need to use references here, subroutine arguments are already passed by reference.

If you do not want to use string eval, you need to use a construct that supports runtime modification.  For that you can use the `s///` operator:

```
sub subst {$_[0] =~ s/($_[1]|0)/$1 ? 0 : $_[1]/ge}

my $z = 1230;

subst $z => 2;

print "$z\n"; # 1032
```

The `tr///` construct is faster than `s///` since the latter supports regular expressions.

Comment: :D I enjoy your code but in the end is the same as mine but compressed. I was more looking for another way of doing it. Anyway, I'll appreciate it very much.

Comment: What type of `another way of doing it` were you expecting?  This could be done with `s///`, it could be done with lazy construction of the `tr` in a subroutine instead of creating all the elements of an array, it could be stored in a hash to work with more than just numbers...

Comment: A way without code inside strings and without repetition of code and without eval and with few code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest simply ditching `tr` in favor of something that actually permits a little bit of metaprogramming like `s///`. For example:

```
# Replace $to_swap with 0 and 0 with $to_swap, and leave
# everything else alone.
sub swap_with_0 {
    my ($digit, $to_swap) = @_;
    if ($digit == $to_swap) {
        return 0;
    } elsif ($digit == 0) {
        return $to_swap;
    } else {
        return $digit;
    }
}

# Swap 0 and $to_swap throughout $string
sub swap_digits {
    my ($string, $to_swap) = @_;
    $string =~ s/([0$to_swap])/swap_with_0($1, $to_swap)/eg;
    return $string;
}
```

which is surprisingly straightforward. :)

Comment: I think you miss brackets and the `g` modifier in the substitution

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short subroutine that uses substitution instead of transliteration:

```
sub swap_digits {
    my ($str, $digit) = @_;
    $str =~ s{ (0) | $digit }{ defined $1 ? $digit : 0 }gex;
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: That's an evil trick, using capturing-or-not to distinguish between the digit and 0, and not really suitable for a beginner ;)